# Generating a controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, terminal

I have a problem when I try to generate a controller with:

```
rails generate controller profiles show
```

I already tried this solution, but didn't work:

```
script/rails generate controller profiles show
./script/rails generate controller profiles show
```

Some errors:

```
/Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:17:in `check_validity!': Either :with or :without must be supplied (but not both) (ArgumentError)
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validator.rb:143:in `initialize'
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:82:in `new'
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:82:in `block in validates_with'
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:81:in `each'
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:81:in `validates_with'
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:99:in `block in validates'
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `each'
from /Users/italoborges/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activemodel-3.2.12/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `validates'
from /Volumes/Development/development/ruby/Tasker/0001_Hello/04_Desenvolvimento/Ruby/app/models/user.rb:14:in `<class:User>'
```

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Check your `user.rb` file. There's an issue with how you defined a validation. This doesn't really have any impact on the controllers, but since the generator loads your application when it runs, any uncaught errors will cause it to fail.

Comment: Thank you Zach!!! The error was in user.rb. An incomplete line.

Comment: @Italo - you should answer your own question below so that this question doesn't show up in the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

The error was in a file, user.rb. An incomplete line.